# Connect QGIS to a database in MS SQL server

Tags: qgis, sql, drivers

I have to link QGIS to MS server using my credentials. Everything seems to go well (I have access to the server and I get the list of all the databases inside) but when comes the time to access to one of the databases (for which I have access), I have an error below:

> Error opening connection: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Client driver version is not supported. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed QODBC3: Unable to connect.

Is this a known issue in QGIS? If yes can you please help me solving it?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?